# Edit/replace Wordpress TwentyTwelve default menu

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to edit the default menu for Wordpress TwentyTwelve theme. So far I have made the sub-menus horizontal but they don't align the same in Firefox than Chrome.
In Ff it looks as I want, but in Chrome, the sub menu align with the Menu item previously clicked, NOT to the far left of the main menu.
basically, I want a horizontal two-lines menu. I can' t get the "position:"" properly.
Here's how it looks in both browsers:

Here's how it looks in both browser:
Chrome: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/248/cssmenuchrome.jpg/

I can't post more links because I need 10 reputation but the second image  (menu in Firefox) in there too.

And here's a fiddle of my code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZN9my/

```
.main-navigation li ul ul {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
  .main-navigation .menu-item li {
        display: none;
        margin-right: 14px !important;
    }
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a constructive answer if you isolate the problem to a smaller block of code.

Comment: Ok I have edited and shortened the code part. There's a fiddle that shows the whole thing. I really need help on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, as you say, is that both browsers seem to be dealing with your `position:absolute;` differently.  `position:absolute` should be calculated in regards to the most recent parent element with an explicitly set `position`, which means that it's actually Chrome which is interpreting it right.

In this case, you've given `.main-navigation li` a `position:relative`, which means that Chrome is positioning the submenu, `li.sub-menu`, relative to it.  If you remove `position-relative` from the CSS for `.main-navigation li` and add it to `ul#menu-main`, then `li.sub-menu` will be positioned relative to the main navigation ul, and should behave as you want it to across browsers.  You'll probably want to change `.main-navigation li ul`'s `top` from `100%` to something like `37px` so it still sits in the right place.

I've made the changes to your jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ZN9my/1/.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Your explanation is clear and perfect; I've learned something today. Your help is extremely appreciated, thank you again!

Comment: I have a second part to my problem:  
Once you click on a sub-menu item and go to that page, I need the submenu line to keep displaying entirely with the current page (sub-menu-item) in bold.  

I have added
`.main-navigation .current-menu-item {
  display: inline !important;
 }`
  
But it only shows the "current" sub-menu item, not the whole list.
  
I fear that this is not pure CSS but maybe some Wordpress line needs to be edited.  

Is there a simple way?
There's the jsfiddle:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/v95Bg) 

I'm sorry to ask for help again but I really tried before asking.

Comment: This would be better as a question rather than as a comment.  But I've fixed it for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/v95Bg/1/.  Your issue is that you're specifying behavior for the `.current-menu-item`, which is just one li, when you need to use CSS that will include all the `ul.sub-menu li` for the current page (I use `.current-page-ancestor`= li`, but you have other choices).

Comment: This is just fantastic, you're a savior! Thank you so much; I wish I had your skills. Thanks again! And next time I'll make it a question rather than a comment.